# Trouble with getline when using eclipse's console

Tags: c++, eclipse, getline

I recently started to use eclipse for my C++ code, and wanted to run a simple function that asks the user for a filename, then reads from the file and sums up all the numbers to test it out.

```
string filename;
do {
    cout << "Enter File Name: "; // Asks for user input
    getline(cin, filename);
}
while (filename.empty());

ifstream myfile (filename);
if (myfile.is_open()) {
    // sums up text file & outputs it
}
else {
    cout << "Error Opening " << filename << endl;
}
```

The program works perfectly when I run it via Windows Command Prompt in my executable folder and type in the filename. However, when I try to run it via eclipse's console using the exact same input, where I've set the working directory to the project root where the file most definitely exists, the file does not open.

If I change a single line:

```
ifstream myfile("test1.txt");
```

Then the code works again perfectly. So now I've narrowed down that for some reason, the Eclipse console interprets my text input via getline differently from the windows command prompt, but I'm not sure what I can do so it behaves consistently.

Calling

```
cin.ignore()
```

Before calling getline() just removes the first character of my input (so it tries to "est1.txt") instead.

Any idea what exactly eclipse does to its console that makes getline unreliable? And if this is the case, what I should do to work around it?

Comment: What is the contents of "filename" when it fails?

Comment: My program outputs: "Error Opening test1.txt" - I am unable to input console commands at all when I run the debugger using eclipse.

Comment: You may want to change the message a little bit -- maybe `cout << "Error Opening '" << filename << "' " << filename.size() << endl;` -- that will help to detect any unprintable characters or other surprises in the string.

Comment: Aha! That was the problem! New output showed that it added a newline character at the end. I've since added a trim function to my string and now it works in all situations. Definitely should have done that to begin with. Thanks!